# Contrast between closure of open ball and closed ball.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

We can make a metric space $X$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ where $\overline{B_r(x)}\neq B_r[x]$.  For example we can take $X=\mathbb R^2-\{(x,y):0<x<1\}$.  Consider $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ in $X$.  Take $\overline{B_1(0)}$ and $B_1[0]$.See that $(1,0)\in B_1[0]$ and $(1,0)\notin \overline {B_1(0)}$.

[image]

See that $(1,0)$ is not a limit point of $B_1(0)$.  I think this is a more lively examples than unit balls of discrete metric which seem quite artificial.  This situation is easy to visualize why the inclusion may be proper.  Can someone provide me with some information as what further things related to these I can look into.  For example I have seen that if for every ball,  closure of open ball is corresponding closed ball in a metric space $X$,  then open balls are connected.

Comment: Honestly, I find your example far more contrived and artificial than that of the discrete metric, which is a standard counterexample.  However, if you want a non-trivial example which is not completely *ad hoc*, consider the $p$-adic numbers for your favorite prime number $p$.  Every ball is clopen, thus $B_{<}(x,1) = \overline{B_{<}(x,1)}$ (the closure of ever "metrically open" or "stripped" ball is itself).  However, $B_{\le}(x,1) = B_{<}(x,p)$ (the "metrically closed" or "dressed" ball of radius $1$ is equal to a stripped ball of greater radius).

Comment: Can someone please give me a hint why $(1,0)\notin \overline{B_1(0)}$?

Comment: @Averroes2 Follow the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb R$ there are also easy examples, like $X=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$, where $2 \in B_1[1]$ but $2 \notin \overline{B_1(1)}$. Of course always $\overline{B_r(x)} \subseteq B_r[x]$ for any $x \in X, r>0$.

It's fun to point out that it *can* happen, as many intuitions are built on the Euclidean space, where we have convex balls, where this phenomenon doesn't occur. But it's not an important thing IMHO.

Comment: IMHO ?.....................

Comment: @KishalaySarkar google it